# Possible to create two different sized arrays/matrices from a file?

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

Basically, I'm trying to create two different sized 2D arrays from a text file that looks like this:

```
2
add
3 4
2 1 7 -10
0 5 -3 12
1 7 -2 -5
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 0 1
subtract
2 2
2 12
10 0
4 6 
9 1
```

The `2` is the number of problems (add and subtract), the `3` and `4` are the number of rows and columns, and the numbers below it are the two separate matrices being filled into the 2D arrays. If I just stop there, this program works correctly:

```
class Matrices {
private Scanner fileReader;
private int rows;
private int columns;
int problems;
String method;

public Matrices(String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this.fileReader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
    problems = fileReader.nextInt();
    method = fileReader.next();

    if(method.equals("add")) {
        rows = fileReader.nextInt();
        columns = fileReader.nextInt();
    }

}

public int[][] readMatrix() throws FileNotFoundException {
    int[][] result = new int[rows][columns];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            result[i][j] = fileReader.nextInt();
        }
    }
    return result;
}


public int[][] add(int[][] a, int[][] b) {
    int[][] result = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
               result[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
           }
       }
       return result;
}

public void printMatrix(int[][] matrix) {
    for ( int[] anArray : matrix ) {
        for ( int anInt : anArray ) {
            System.out.print(anInt+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

With this driver:

```
    public class MatricesDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter name of file: ");
    String filename = keyboard.next();

    Matrices matrixReader = new Matrices(filename);
    int[][] a = matrixReader.readMatrix();
    int[][] b = matrixReader.readMatrix();

    System.out.println("Matrix 1: ");
    matrixReader.printMatrix(a);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Matrix 2: ");
    matrixReader.printMatrix(b);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Addition: ");
    int[][] addition = matrixReader.add(a,b);
    matrixReader.printMatrix(addition);

    }
}
```

It creates and prints the matrices just fine, with no problems. However, whenever I try to create and print the next two matrices (the 2x2 arrays below subtract in the text file), it returns the following error:

```
Enter name of file: 
data/Matrices.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at baker.Matrices.readMatrix(Matrices.java:27)
    at baker.MatricesDriver.main(MatricesDriver.java:15
```

My question is, what adjustments should I make so that the program recognizes that two of the 2D arrays are to be 3x4, and the two following are to be 2x2?

Comment: Is the text format given?

Comment: The text file? Yes its just as it is listed there, no spaces and no separate files

Comment: By no spaces I mean no spaces between lines, apologies for the ambiguity

Comment: The main problem is that you only initialize once the rows and columns in the constructor of the MatricesDriver. This means it is expexting 3 and 4. And later, if you call readMatrix for the third time it still is working on these dimensions. You need to separate the file reading from the matrix/problem reading.

Comment: Would it just be a huge method defining all of the matrices? Or would it be a bunch of get methods? Sorry I'm pretty new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend decomposing your implementation into the following parts:

- class `Matrix` - holds the values of one matrix from problem definition
- class `Problem` - holds the operation and the two matrices from problem definition

The `Matrix` class could look like:

```
class Matrix {
    private int[][] values;

    public Matrix(int[][] values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public int[][] getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Matrix [values=\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            sb.append("\t" +  Arrays.toString(values[i]) + "\n");
        }
        sb.append("]");
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

The `Problem` class could be:

```
class Problem {
    private String operation;
    private Matrix first;
    private Matrix second;

    public Problem(String operation, Matrix firstMatrix, Matrix secondMatrix) {
        this.operation = operation;
        first = firstMatrix;
        second = secondMatrix;
    }

    public String getOperation() {
        return operation;
    }

    public Matrix getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public Matrix getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Problem [\noperation=" + operation + ", \nfirst=" + first + ", \nsecond=" + second + "\n]";
    }
}
```

Based on this, your "driver" class does the following:

1. Get the filename from user input
2. Read from file the number of problems and construct a list with this initial size
3. For the number of problems (i.e. 2) get the operation, rows, and colums and construct a new Problem object containing these information and put the Problem into the list ...

Here is one simple solution - still room for improvement here :-)

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MatricesDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter name of file: ");
         String filename = keyboard.next();

         List<Problem> problems = readProblems(filename);
         System.out.println(problems);
         keyboard.close();
    }

    private static List<Problem> readProblems(final String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename));
        int numberOfProblems = fileReader.nextInt();
        List<Problem> problems = new ArrayList<>(numberOfProblems);
        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfProblems; i++) {
            problems.add(readProblem(fileReader));
        }
        fileReader.close();
        return problems;
    }

    private static Problem readProblem(Scanner fileReader) throws FileNotFoundException {
        fileReader.nextLine(); // go to next line
        String operation = fileReader.nextLine(); // read problem operation
        int rows = fileReader.nextInt(); // read number of rows 
        int columns = fileReader.nextInt(); // read number of columns
        Matrix firstMatrix = readMatrix(rows, columns, fileReader);
        Matrix secondMatrix = readMatrix(rows, columns, fileReader);
        return new Problem(operation, firstMatrix, secondMatrix);
    }

    private static Matrix readMatrix(final int rows, final int columns, final Scanner fileReader) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int[][] result = new int[rows][columns];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                result[i][j] = fileReader.nextInt();
            }
        }
        return new Matrix(result);
    }

}
```

Tested with your input file.

HTH

Comment: The end game of the code is two add the 3x4 matrices, and subtract the 2x2 matrices., then print them I think I am on the right track, I updated my code.

Comment: Fine. Could you please mark the answer as helpful or correct to close this topic. Thanks.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry. There you go. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You tried to structure your data?

you can use that:

[properties-file](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/)

For create array or vector without a fixed size use arrayList, you can make a arrayList from a arrayList